# Python/Numpy What's it called / how do you represent that operation where you multiply each element of two vectors?

Tags: python, arrays, math, matlab, numpy

For example, suppose I have:

```
x = array([1, 2, 3])
y = array([4, 5, 6])
```

Standard "array multiplication" in python does `z = x * y = array([4, 10, 18])`. In matlab, to get the same effect, you do *. IIRC.

What is this operation called, and which symbol is used to represent it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the Hadamard product represented with an open circle:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are after the expression S = sum_i( x_i * y_i)? That is called the inner product. From numpy documentation:

```
from numpy import *
x = array([1,2,3])
y = array([2,2,2])
inner(x,y)          <-- Should give 1*2 + 2*2 + 3*2 = 12
```

The operation you have illustrated, and what you get with .* in matlab, is called a Schur/Hadamard product, often a small open circle is used as symbol. Since this is what you get with the normal '*' operator in numpy I doubt there is a separate Schur function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are three different ways to multiply all the elements of two vectors.

The first one, the inner or [dot product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html), returns a scalar.

The second one, the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html), returns a vector.

The third one, the [tensor product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpaceTensorProduct.html), returns a second-order tensor.

I'm sure you mean the first one, because it's familiar to most people, but I thought it'd be good to post this for the sake of completeness.

Comment: A perfectly correct answer.  I can't see why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking about. Nevertheless, in MATLAB, x * y is [called](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) matrix multiplication, while x .* y is [called](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) array multiplication.